# unix domain socket - what happens when the rate of recvfrom calls is smaller than sendto calls?

Tags: sockets, ipc

I'm trying to write a light-weight non-blocking performance statistic agent program, unix domain socket with datagram for IPC seems a reasonable choice. I want to know the system behavior when the agent gets unexpectedly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually UDP datagrams will be dropped somewhere or other.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `rmem_max` for udp server. looks like the same applies to unix domain socket with datagram. The system will drop the requests when buffer gets full.